# Initialized variable not returning correct value

Tags: c++, constructor

When I initialize hp, damage, and speed and call the getters, the values returned are not the initialized values, but rather larger negative numbers. What am I missing? Here is my base class and my main.cpp

```
class Character
{
public:
    //constructor to initialize data members
    explicit Character(string cname)
        : name{ cname }, hp{ 10 }, damage{ 5 }, speed{ 2 }
        {}
    Character();
    //call to member function that problem Character depending on user inputs
        virtual void special(); //polymorphic special attack

       int getHp()
        {
            return hp;
        }

        string getName()
        {
            return name;
        }

        int getDamage()
        {
            return damage;
        }

        int getSpeed()
        {
            return speed;
        }

        void setName(std::string cname)
        {
            name = cname;
        }

private:
    string name;
    int hp;
    int damage;
    int speed;


int main()
{
    string name = "";
    int choice = 0;
    //declare Picker class
    Warrior war;
    Mage mage;
    Assassin assn;
    std::vector<Character*> cptr(3);
    cptr[0] = &war;
   
    cout << "Please enter a name for your character\n";
    cin >> name;
    war.setName(name);
    cout << "Here are your characters attributes\n\n";
    cout << "Name is: " << war.getName() << "\n";
```

Calling the base class directly works fine, going through the derived class gives me the large negative number

Adding derived class:

```
#ifndef Warrior_H
#define Warrior_H
#include "Character.h"
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;


class Warrior: public Character
{
public:
    //constructor to initialize data members
    explicit Warrior()
        : attack{ "Berserker Strike" }, weapon {"War Hammer"}
    {}


        void special(); //polymorphic special attack
        void basic();
        string getClassWeapon() { return weapon; }

private:
    string attack;
    string weapon;
};
```

Comment: Welcome! Please make your example self-contained (write a main that constructs the object). Tag question with c++ (I assume).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.  This doesn't compile as you are not closing main with a }.  It refers to classes that you don't define.  My *guess* is that your derived classes don't invoke the base constructor with 1 argument so the default constructor is used with which result is your member variables being undefined values.

Comment: that is correct, I'm not calling the base constructor in my derived class. That's what I'm trying to figure out

Comment: You need to show one of your derived classes then.  You see how you set name{cname}? You need do do Character{cname} or wathever in your derived class.

Comment: added derived class Warrior.h

Answer (score 0):

You need to invoke the right constructor of the base class:

```
  explicit Warrior() : Character(""), attack{ "Berserker Strike" }, weapon {"War Hammer"} {}
```

or update the default constructor to initialize those variables (you might be able to invoke the explicit constructor you already have or use a separate init function):

```
    Character() : name{""}, hp{10}, damage{5} {}
```

Comment: I left out something, I'm using inheritance and calling a derived class object to grab getHp(). Main looks like this: 
Warrior war (derived class)
war.getHp();

This returns large negative number

Comment: This is exactly why you need to post a self-contained example.  Please update question and I will update answer accordingly.  Also minimize the example like I did above to just what is required to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: I've updated the question to include the calling method